# Short story about an aging gardener on a space station, with a resentment of "intruders" in his area?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

**Plot Details/Summary**

As per usual with my recollections, I don't have a whole lot of details.

The story takes place on a permanently inhabited space station, some time well into the future.  The protagonist is the gardener/groundskeeper of the space station's green area/park/scenic gardens. He's been at the job for many years, and has become very protective of the gardens.  He is resentful of intrusion, I *think* by people who don't show the park the proper respect or take it for granted.  There is an internal monologue about outsiders or people who don't belong (I forget the exact terminology).

There may have been an environmental theme to the tale in the vein of the film *Silent Running*, but I cannot recall. I also don't remember much of the "middle" of the story.

I do remember the final portion of the tale, which includes a bit of a twist.  He's skulking about, and is annoyed with a young couple who are having a romantic walk in the gardens.  The woman becomes angry with him and basically calls him a creep and tells him to get lost.

The protagonist then comes to the realization that over his many years of service, he somehow lost perspective of his purpose and what the gardens were there for in the first place.  *He* is the intruder in the gardens, not the people who visit them.  The story closes with the gardener admitting he can no longer be the caretaker as he does not belong there anymore.

**Publication Details/Timeframe**

I am fairly certain I read this story in a mainstream science fiction/fantasy magazine in the 1980s or 1990s, though I do not recall which one.  I mostly read *Analog* and *Fantasy and Science Fiction Magazine* back then, so those are the most likely candidates.  Not sure when the magazine issue was published. It could have been an earlier issue (1970s, etc.)

Comment: Frank Herbert maybe? This feels as something he could have written. I haven't read all his short stories, so I don't know for sure, but some of those I did read have similarities to this.